# How to load an existing layout into my own template in Magento?

Tags: magento, templates, layout

In Magento, preferably without creating a whole new module, how do I load a layout of an existing module it into my own template?

For example: I want to load the "user account dashboard" layout, but I want to load it so that I can control how it looks separately from the default.

The structure is as follows:

1. I have created a CMS page with url "portal". So, the navigation is "http://website.com/portal"
2. The CMS page uses "include()" to load a "/root/portal/portal.php". This is where I define a class that extends Mage_Page_Block_Html.
3. Then I have added a function "renderDashboard()" to load in the dashboard from the existing dashboard layout.
4. I have copied "/app/base/default/customer/account/dashboard.phtml" to "/root/portal/content/dashboard.phtml" to be used as the template. Inside my "dashboard.phtml" I want "$this" object to function exactly the same as it does in the former "dashboard.phtml"

**"/root/portal/portal.php"**

```
class Portal_Block extends Mage_Page_Block_Html 
{
    public function renderDashboard()
    {
        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

        //Load existing "customer/account_dashboard" block into my own "dashboard.phtml"
        $block = $layout->createBlock('customer/account_dashboard')->setTemplate('/root/portal/content/dashboard.phtml');

        //Need to now add it
        //$block->renderLayout(); 
    }
}
```

If this is not possible, I will have to rewrite the entire Account Dashboard module in my portal... So, I'm really hoping it's possible!

Comment: Ultimately, what is your goal?  I ask because the structure you've done so far is full of bad practices.  Including PHP files, saving files outside of the Magento code-base structure is just a hackish and unstable way of achieving your goal.  You may want to consider following the Magento standards, or hire an experienced developer to do it for you as what you're doing now will cause you headaches in the future, if you decide to upgrade.

Comment: Basically just to create a separate user account page, same content, but different template. However, ... according to you it seems I'm way off in the way that I started. What would you suggest? The creating of a new module? I was wondering if there was a way around that, and to just use PHP class overriding and property inheritance.

Comment: Are you concerned with it being on custom URL? `/portal` for instance, or are you just trying to customize the standard account page?  If you're wanting two account pages (Magento default, AND your custom one), the proper way would be to write an extension that mimics the account controller.  If you're just wanting the account to be accessible from `/portal` you can use the built in URL Rewriting in the Magento back-end to achieve this.  If that's what you want, let me know and I'll outline the steps to do that in a proper answer.

Comment: The "/portal" page is what I'm after. So that can just be a url rewrite? As long as I am able to write my own extra PHP code there as well, because there are a couple new features to go on this new "/portal" page.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Creating the Redirects

Create a rewrite rule, pointing `portal/` to `customer/account/`

1. Go to **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management**, click the **Add URL Rewrite Button**
2. Change the **Type** to `custom`
3. Set **ID Path** to `portal`
4. Set **Request Path** to `portal`
5. Set **Target Path** to `customer/account/`
6. Set **Redirect** to `No`
7. Press the **Save** button

Test this direct by going to `yoursite.com/portal`.  It should automatically load the `customer/account/` page.

Now redirect legacy `customer/account/` links back to `/portal`

1. Go to **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management**, click the **Add URL Rewrite Button**
2. Change the **Type** to `custom`
3. Set **ID Path** to `redirect_to_portal`
4. Set **Request Path** to `customer/account/`
5. Set **Target Path** to `portal`
6. Set **Redirect** to `Permanent (301)`
7. Press the **Save** button

Test by going to `yoursite.com/customer/account/`.  It should redirect automatically to `/portal`

### Step 2: Modifying the Account Page Template

The account page is made up of several template files.  These file locations may vary slightly, depending on if you're using a custom template and whether or not that template overrides the Magento base template files.

Look under `app/design/frontend/default/base/template/customer/account/`.

Here you will find the `.phtml` files related to the account pages.  If you have a custom template that overrides these files, you wlll need to modify the files in your template directory.  Example: `app/design/frontend/[TEMPLATE_NAME]/[TEMPLATE_NAME]/template/customer/account/`

The `dashboard.phtml` file is the main template file for the dashboard page.

You can also look in the `app/design/frontend/default/base/layout/customer.xml` and look for the `<customer_account_index>` tags.  Here you can see what `.phtml` files and what blocks are being loaded into the account template.

Comment: Hm, sorry I guess I left out the bit that I wanted "website.com/customer/account" to remain exactly the same. "/portal" would use that same page, but in a different template.